# Github 403 (connection refused) while installing rvm

Tags: github, rvm

I am trying to install rvm from the official install page. 
Running this is broken:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ghufran/.rvm/src/rvm/.git/
fatal: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm.git/info/refs download error - The requested URL returned error: 403

ERROR: Unable to clone the RVM repository, attempted both git:// and https://
```

I am using `ubuntu 9.1 64 bit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after looking into this, i figured out it wasn't related to rvm at all.

The problem was with my network and the port used for git protocol was not open. Opening the port worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

base on the tutorial [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux_3.htm)

did you install all the development libraries like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libreadline5-dev libssl-dev
libxml2-dev
```

??

I just installed rvm successfully following the tutorial I just mentioned on my Ubuntu 11.04 box. and I don't think the version of the OS is a big problem.

beside, there is NO `Ubuntu 9.1`, it's `Ubuntu 9.10`, which means released Oct, 2009.

Comment: Hey, I was able to fix the issue. It turned out to be an issue with my network. The port for git protocol was closed and so the download for the rvm script failed. 

It was strange because other repositories that were over ssh were working fine..

Yes, i know it is 9.10! just use 9.1 as a shorthand..